# this file is not displayed in the editor

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I tried to upload fonts by creating a new folder with the same name 
and here is the yaml file

> ```
> fonts:
>  - family: Lobster
>    fonts:
>      - asset: fonts/Lobster-Regular.ttf
> ```
>
> and in main

```
Text('Dong Shik', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Lobster' ,fontSize: 20.0, )
```

but when I open the font's file I get this error

this file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding

and when I launch the app nothing shows just a white page?

Answer (score 0):

**you use wrong declaration in .yaml , try this..**

```
fonts:
- family: Lobster
  fonts:
    - asset: fonts/Lobster.ttf
```

**And after that in main dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

       return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Custom Font',
    theme: ThemeData(

        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
            fontFamily: 'Lobster')),
    home: Home());}}
```